# Search for multiple terms in cell and return portion of string in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to look inside a cell for multiple criteria and if found return a portion of the text inside. It's an address cell. I'm looking for ";" "," "•" and if found I want to split the cell contents into Address 1 and Address 2. I have the formula working far enough to ascertain if something needs to be done to the cell but if falls apart afterwards. It only works if it finds a ";" and returns #VALUE if it finds one of the other two.

For Address 1

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({";",",","•"},D2)))))>0,LEFT(D2,SEARCH({";",",","•"},D2)-1),D2)
```

For Address 2

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({";",",","•"},D2)))))>0,TRIM(RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-SEARCH({";",",","•"},D2))),"")
```

How can I make this formula pull back the right data when finding one of the other two criteria. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You tag VBA, so if that's possible, I'd look into [Regular Expressions](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html). Seems like a prime candidate.